# How to retrieve rows based on duplicate value in specific column in Pandas Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

Let's Say we have data as follows:

```
 A       B
123     John
456     Mary
102     Allen
456     Nickolan
123     Richie    
167     Daniel
```

We want to get retrieve rows based on column A if duplicated then store in different dataframes with that code name.

```
[123  John, 123  Richie], These both will be stored in df_123
[456 Mary, 456 Nickolan], These both will be stored in df_456
[102 Allen] will be stored in df_102
[167 Daniel] will be stored in df_167
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: `dfs = {'df_{}'.format(k): v for k, v in df.groupby('A') if len(v) > 1}` might help.

Comment: Thanks for help, it worked for duplicates. but still requires little changes for rows including duplicates and unique too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

group and then use list comprehension, which will return a list of dataframes based on the group:

```
group = df.groupby('A')
dfs = [group.get_group(x) for x in group.groups]

[     A       B
 2  112   Allen
 5  112  Daniel,      A       B
 0  123    John
 4  123  Richie,      A         B
 1  456      Mary
 3  456  Nickolan]
```

Answer (score 2):

#### [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) + [`tuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-tuple) + [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-dict)

Creating a variable number of variables is not recommended. You can use a dictionary:

```
dfs = dict(tuple(df.groupby('A')))
```

And that's it. To access the dataframe where `A == 123`, use `dfs[123]`, etc.

Note your dataframes are now distinct objects. You can no longer perform operations on `dfs` and have them applied to each dataframe value without a Python-level loop.

Comment: I really like this approach